# how to avoid the buffer from closing in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Assume now I have opened File A and then I type C-X-3. Now I have another window with File A. 
However, if I want to replace File A with File B in the new window by typing C-X C-V, the old window will replace File A with Scratch. How to avoid old window doing this extra action? I mean in fact I do not want to close File A in the old window.
Thanks.

Comment: Is it?:  `M-x switch-to-buffer`  Or, is it?: `M-x switch-to-buffer-other-window`  Or, perhaps?:  `M-x find-file-other-window`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C-x C-v is usually bound to `find-alternate-file`, which closes the previous buffer. Seems, this is not what you want.

To open a new file, use C-x C-f (`find-file`), to select an existing buffer, use C-x C-b.

Generally, to find out what a keybinding does, use `C-h k` and then type the key combination you are curious about. This will give you the name of the command and a short description. You can then do C-h F (i.e. upper case F) and type in the name of the command: this will show you the relevant section of the manual, in your case various ways of opening a file.